# What is the difference between Scrapy's spider middleware and downloader middleware?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

Both middleware can process Request and Response. But what is the difference?

Comment: @MitchWheat: It may look trivial, but it's a good question.

Comment: Doesn't appear to have any programming content: looks like a question for a search engine.

Comment: @MitchWheat: The distinction between the two isn't obvious and isn't explained in the documentation. Casting downvotes and close votes isn't really helpful if you don't understand the framework involved.

Comment: I just wanted to say that both the question and answer helped me greatly. I wished it had remained open, so more helpful answers could be posted.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

While they have almost identical interfaces, they serve different purposes:

- Downloader middlewares modify requests and responses or generate requests in response to responses. They don't directly interact with spiders. Some examples are middlewares that implement cookies, caching, proxies, redirects, setting user-agent headers, etc. They just add functionality to the downloader system.
- Spider middlewares modify things that pass in and out of spiders, like requests, items, exceptions, and `start_requests`. They do share some basic functionality with downloader middlewares, but they can't generate requests in response to responses. They stand between the spiders and the downloader. One example is filtering out responses with bad HTTP status codes.

Some middlewares can function as either a downloader middleware or a spider middleware, but they're often trivial and will be forced into one category or the other once you add more complex functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the solution that helps me a lot. Can you please elaborate the role of DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES here.@Blender